# Convert object data to html in python

Tags: python, html, django, list, object

I want to convert [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2hQ4.png) to html tag with django template

Code in view:

```
def selectbeds(request):
    """Docstring."""
    try:
        all_beds = Beds.objects.all()
        all_beds_seri = serializers.serialize('json', all_beds)
        all_beds_json = json.loads(all_beds_seri)
        data = json.dumps(all_beds_json)
        table = json2html.convert(json=data)
        return render(request, 'beds_show.html', {'context': table})
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse(e.args)
```

And code in beds_show.html:

```
   <div class="col-md-9 content" style="border:1px solid red">
      {{ context }}
   </div>
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: i want to show table not code

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I used this

view:

```
def selectbeds(request):
    """Docstring."""
    bed = []
    try:
        for i in Beds.objects.all():
            bed.extend([(i.number, i.nurce.name, i.person.name)])
        return render(request, 'beds_show.html', {'bed': bed})
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse(e.args)
```

and template:

```
{% for i in bed %}
  <tr>
    <td class="w-25" scope="row">
      bed number: {{ i.0 }}
    </td>
    <td class="w-25" scope="row">
      {{ i.1 }}
    </td>
    <td class="w-25" scope="row">
      {{ i.2 }}
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```